# Selenium - Writing a file to codemirror with line breaks

Tags: javascript, java, json, selenium, codemirror

I'm writing a selenium test which writes a JSON file to a CodeMirror window. Here's my code so far:

```
public void setJson(String jsonPath) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    // Read a file to a string
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(jsonPath));
    String jsonText = new String(encoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    // Get rid of line breaks
    jsonText = jsonText.replace("\n", "");
    // Escape the quotes
    jsonText = jsonText.replace("\"", "\\\"");

    // Write to the CodeMirror
    WebElement queryInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"content\"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div"));
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].CodeMirror.setValue(\"" + jsonText + "\");", queryInput);

}
```

This code works. But it writes the whole JSON file on one line. Here's a few things I tried.

1. Not replacing the "\n". This gives an "unterminated string literal" error
2. Replacing "\n" with "\r". Same error.
3. Replacing "\n" with "<\br>" (without that backslash. I can't even do line breaks right on stack overflow). This just put a bunch of "br" tags in the json text.

Any ideas? I'm guessing there is a way to do this line by line, but I'd rather be able to just send the whole file as one string.

Comment: What is your JSON? Does it have line-breaks already, or are you looking for a pretty printer?

Comment: Please paste your JSON as well so that we can help you better. Also a wild guess here.. try replacing "\n" using "\\n"

Comment: The JSON had line breaks ("\n"), but if I left them there, I got the "unterminated string literal" error. I replaced them with "\\n" and everything worked! Thanks Vedanshu!

Comment: For me it's worked with `\\r`.. Thanks guys!!!

Answer (score -1):

To get rid of line breaks

Try:

```
jsonText = jsonText.replaceAll("\n", "\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n"); // for all occurrence
// This will replace \n with \\\\r\\\\n a new line for codemirror
```

or

```
jsonText = jsonText.replace("\n", "\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n");
```